# How can get value in @Html.Textboxfor with js and check null?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <p>ID: @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.user_id)</p>
            <p>Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.user_name)</p>
            <input type="submit" />
        }
```

This is my code. I have to check null value when person click submit button. If person input null, Web will show alert.

And I tried to give id to hteml.textboxfor().

```
            <p>ID: @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.user_id, new {id= "user_id"})</p>
```

I'm not sure if this code is right. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.TextBoxFor` will automatically generate id `user_id`.

And you can do it like below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>ID: @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.user_id)</p>
    <p>Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.user_name)</p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
}

@section scripts{ 
<script>
    $("#submit").on("click", function (e) {
        var id = $("#user_id").val();
        var name = $("#user_name").val();
        if (id == "" || name == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("value can't be null");
        }
    })
</script>
```

**Update:**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        var id = document.getElementById("user_id").value;
        var name = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
        if (id == "" || name == "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("value can't be null");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! Btw is there any way to write a script code in Vanilla JS? I'm so curious!!!!